# Angular 7 Service Worker setup - ngsw-worker.js registration error

Tags: angular, angular6, service-worker, angular7, service-worker-events

**Issue:**

Currently get ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE and /ngsw-config.json:-Infinity
Parser error: for the ngsw-worker.js file in the network traffic.

**See image below:**

[image]

**Tech:** Angular cli and Angular version 7.

**Things I've done**

**I've added these tags to the index.html head:**

```
  <link rel="manifest" src="manifest.json">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#2c3e50">
```

**My Manifest.json:**

```
{
  "short_name": "test",
  "name": "test.co.uk",
  "start_url": "/",
  "background_color": "#2c3e50",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "theme_color": "#2c3e50",
  "icons": []
}
```

**My angular.json file:**

```
"serviceWorker": true
```

For:

"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": { "serviceWorker": true

**My Main.ts file:**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js') ;
    }
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**My ngsw-worker.js file:**

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/index.html"
      ],
      "versionedFiles": [
        "/*.bundle.css",
        "/*.bundle.js",
        "/*.chunk.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  }],
  "dataGroups": [{
    "name": "api-freshness",
    "urls": [
      "/new"
    ],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "maxSize": 100,
      "maxAge": "1h",
      "timeout": "10s",
      "strategy": "freshness"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "api-performance",
    "urls": [
      "/"
    ],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "maxSize": 100,
      "maxAge": "1d",
      "strategy": "performance"
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw in the chrome devtools that your staging site is trying to load the service worker from the file ngsw-config.json instead of ngsw-worker.js. Could it be that you mixed up these two files?

[image: chorme dev tools of https://behired-staging.firebaseapp.com/]

The service-worker is always registered with a js file (normally ngsw-worker.js) and then the service worker fetches the configuration from e.g. ngsw-config.json

So the load order in the network tab should look like:

[image: load order service worker]

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting it in IIS then you should add MimeType for json type in web.config -

For example:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
     <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```